# maven release perform failed

Tags: maven, release, failed-installation

Today while doing the release of our project, the release:perform command failed in between as our nexus was having intermittent issues. The release command only able to upload one pom file to nexus.

Now, the nexus issue is resolved and I am trying to do the release, it fails as the pom file already exists and its not the snapshot version and we don't have access to nexus so that I can delete that file and start over again.

Is there any way I can pass an argument so that release:perform should continue if the file is already there and ignore this but continue with uploading the rest.

I have looked for options of such type but didn't find anything.

My last resource would be to start the release again, which will bump the version number, but would like to understand if there is any other approach where in I don't need to bump the version.

I am using maven 2.2.1

Answer (score 10):

Here's how I have handled this in the past. The `release:perform` command does a checkout of the tag from your SCM provider (e.g. SVN). This is done in the `target/checkout` directory of that project - whatever is there should be an exact copy of the released tag, so it will have the right version number in the pom files etc.

If you move to that directory (`target/checkout` in the directory where you started the release), you can simply do a `mvn deploy` there and it should compile and package that version, and then upload it to your Nexus instance.

If you don't have the `target/checkout` directory, you can check out the Tag created as part of the `release:prepare` phase from your SCM system to a fresh directory and run `mvn deploy` there.

Since the tag in your SCM has already been created, the only thing that's left is really compiling, packaging and deploying the release, which is exactly what `mvn deploy` should do.

If you have provided additional parameters (e.g. for activating profiles) for the build during the call to `mvn release:perform`, you will have to provide these as well when you run `mvn deploy`.

Using this approach, your version number will not have to change, it can stay the same, since you're just uploading what has already been tagged as part of `mvn release:prepare`.

Comment: Problem here is not that I can't perform what you suggested, I can do that but when release:perform tries to deploy the file to nexus, it fails as the pom file is already there.

Comment: Then you really need to talk to an admin to get the file removed. If that can't be done, then your only chance is to increase the version number and recreate the release. I often append an index to the version in this case. If your failed release was 1.2.3, then your new one should be something like 1.2.3-1. Getting the pom file removed from Nexus would be the better option, though.

Comment: If you don't follow the advice in the comments to my answer above, then you can simply do this as well, although it will leave the leftovers of unnecessary artifacts in your repository (albeit you may have removed the tag).

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be for you to request from the admins that the old artifact be removed. You can either re-deploy the code from the tag by checking it out and simply doing

```
mvn deploy
```

Or rolling back your release:

```
mvn release:rollback
```

And re-doing it as usual.

It is essential to remove the old artifact from the remote repository, if the sizes do not match. Release repositories do not allow the redeployment of artifacts, unless this has been explicitly switched on on the server side.

Furthermore, @nwinkler's answer is also quite good.

Comment: Good suggestion (removing the artifact). I think `release:rollback` doesn't roll back the tag or remove the deployed artifact, right? These are manual admin tasks, I think.

Comment: Problem we get got here is that admin of our nexus has left the company and no one now has the access, so we can use it as is, but cant delete the files.

Comment: Indeed `mvn release:rollback` does not remove the tag (which we all would really expect from it, it just reverts the version of the project(s)).

Comment: Well, 'hacking' Nexus in this case is not really all that complicated. If you have access to the machine (preferably the user running Nexus or root), you can follow the steps described here:  https://docs.sonatype.com/display/SPRTNXOSS/Nexus+FAQ#NexusFAQ-Q.HowcanIresetaforgottenadminpassword%3F

Comment: You can always try the default user/pass: admin/admin123 to see if the admin ever changed these credentials. :)

Comment: (Sonatype's site is up and down today for maintenance, but the link will be valid after they're done).

Comment: release:rollback seems pointless, it submits poms with a previous versions to the head of the VCS.  Due to artifacts being out there, and the releases commit existing in VCS release:rollback does not achieve anything with SVN as the client.
Perhaps with GIT it actually deletes the commit?

Comment: @teknopaul: I agree, but that's how the plugin works. Nowadays, there are much more sophisticated Maven release plugins. You have to bear in mind that this answer was for the `maven-release-plugin` from back in 2013.